# How to create an online multi-user quiz

Tags: web-applications, google-forms, multi-user, google-form-quiz

The idea is to create an online multi-user quiz in which each user can log-in with a specific role and there is a story line where the answers of a first user modify the questions of other users.

Can I accomplish this by adapting google forms or some other type of open source tool?
Or if I wanted to make a web app, which technologies and libraries should I use?

Do you have any guidelines to give me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Nodejs for the backend, you will need to use socket.io or socketcluster to transmit data in realtime. For authentication i suggest Passport.js.

PassportJS: http://www.passportjs.org

SocketIO: https://socket.io/docs/

Another solution is:

SocketCluster: https://socketcluster.io/docs/getting-started/

Nodejs: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/

Comment: could you update your answer by giving the necessary URL?